# Insert Timestamp when copy/paste whole row and value inserts/edits in Column C in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried inserting timestamp when a row is being copied and data inserts or edits in Column C same row cell, but it works only on manual entry, not on copy-paste.
Please suggest to me what I am missing or doing wrong.

```
function onChange() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();

  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var ar = s.getActiveRange();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the active range = "+ar.getA1Notation()+", the number of rows = "+ar.getNumRows());
  

  if( r.getColumn() == 3 && sName == 'Sheet1') { //which column to watch on which sheet
   // loop through the number of rows
    for (var i = 0;i<arRows;i++){
      var rowstamp = row+i;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F' + rowstamp.toString()).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"); //which column to put timestamp in
    }
  }
 }//setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: `but it works only on manual entry, not on copy-paste` I cannot reproduce this, timestamp is getting added on copy-paste too, as expected. I assume you mean copying some cell to column 3, right? **Note**: If you're copying multiple cells and the top-left one is not in column three, you'll have to rework your code a bit for this to work. Maybe this is what's going on?

Comment: Yes, exactly top-left remains in column A only and I need to copy and paste the whole row, suppose row 8 copied with cells A8, B8, C8, D8, E8.

Comment: I thought the edited/pasted range should include column C, that the timestamp should be in column F only, and that the timestamps should be emptied when the selected range is emptied. Isn't that the case? Since you accepted an answer that doesn't address these issues, I'm confused.

Comment: Exactly, but including your and his too, I got my way around therefor I accepted both answers.
My actual working code is
````
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var ar = e.range;
  var row = ar.getRow();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows();
  if( ar.getColumn() == 3  && sName == 'Sheet1' || e.range.getValue().length > 0) { 
      s.getRange(row,6,arRows).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
 }

````

Comment: C is the first column is not a part of my request, secondly, it is working fine for pasting n number of rows and removing timestamps when a row is being emptied.
I tried accepting both answers but there is a limitation to approve one I guess.
Sorry for the confusion it is causing sir.

Comment: `C is the first column is not a part of my request` I think you misunderstood my point. You wanted to add a timestamp to column F even if the pasted range does **not** start in column C. In the code you provided, that's not the case (for example, if you past to range A3:E3, a timestamp won't be added). I hope that is clear now ;)

Comment: @Iamblichus I worked with the OP on another question this is why I might have answered something that maybe is not explained well in his current question. Pratibha you can't accept both answers, you can only accept one. But keep your current accepted to Iamblichus if you want. Just don't change it back and forth.

Comment: @Marios That might certainly be the case. According to what the OP said in this question, I thought the edited/pasted range should include column C, that the timestamp should be in column F only, and that the timestamps should be emptied when the selected range is emptied. Since your answer was not tackling these issues and was accepted anyway, I asked for clarification. Let me know if there's anything I'm missing :)

Comment: @Iamblichus you are correct, I didn't read carefully his question. I just relied on the fact that it worked for him, this is why I didn't change my code. I will upvote yours to give it more weight to the future readers :)

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion created to both of you,@lamblichus, I have got your point and will stick to it. I highly appreciate your efforts and prompt responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastcolumn) to check whether column C is included in the pasted range.
- Use [getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) to get the number of rows your copied range has, and so add the timestamp to all these rows.
- No need to used an installed [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) for this, a simple [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) is enough.
- I'd also suggest to use [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) in order to get information on which range was edited (even though this way you won't be able to fire this successfully from the script editor).
- **Edit**: if you want to remove the timestamp when the range is cleared, you can just check that's the case, using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) if that's the case.

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var firstRow = r.getRow();
  var numRows = r.getNumRows();
  var firstCol = r.getColumn();
  var lastCol = r.getLastColumn();
  if((firstCol <= 3 || lastCol >= 3) && s.getName() == 'Sheet1') {
    var emptyRange = r.getValues().every(row => row.every(value => value === ""));
    var destRange = s.getRange(firstRow, 6, numRows);
    if (emptyRange) destRange.clearContent();
    else {
      var dates = new Array(numRows).fill([new Date()]);
      destRange.setValues(dates).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @lamblichus,your solution also worked

Answer (score 1):

The following script will create timestamps starting from column `F` until the last column when you copy the row.

I think you are looking for this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const startCol = 6; // column F
  const s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sName = s.getName();
  const ar = e.range;
  const row = ar.getRow();
  const arColumns = ar.getNumColumns();
  const arRows = ar.getNumRows();;
  if( sName == 'Sheet1') { 
     const rng = s.getRange(row,1,arRows,s.getMaxColumns());
     check = rng.getValues().flat().every(v=>v=='');
     if(check){
         rng.clearContent();
     }
     else{
      s.getRange(row,startCol,arRows,s.getMaxColumns()-startCol+1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
     }
  }
 }
```

**Note:**

Again, [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) is a trigger function. You are **not** supposed to execute it manually and if you do so you will actually get errors (because of the use of the event object). All you have to do is to **save** this code snippet to the script editor and then it will be triggered automatically upon edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marios, I again appreciate your prompt response, it works exactly except that if we copy 5 rows at a time then the timestamp appears only on the 1st row instead of all 5 rows which is exactly what I am looking for.
I am trying to use the arRows variable, is this the right way to write?
and also when I am deleting rows timestamp is not vanishing.

Thank you again :)

Comment: @PratibhaRajpoot Did the updated answer work?

Comment: Yes, Marios your solution gave me the hints and it worked for me.